# why is htaccess redirecting twice?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have the following on my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /error/notfound
```

Everytime i go to a page it does send the request to index but it does it twice. I created an index with just `<?die("here");` and put a breakpoint there. It gets hit twice. Any ideas what is wrong with my htaccess? Funny thing is that the first request renders on the page so its not really a redirect. Almost like the htaccess is calling index twice per request. Any help would be most appreciated :)

Comment: How do you know it is being called twice? I would assume that is an issue of your IDE.

Comment: that doesnt happen with other websites i work on. same IDE same computer

Comment: i think i just figured out... second request is for favicon.ico

Comment: I was just typing that it was the favicon.ico file

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem was that i hadnt created a favicon.ico yet so it was redirecting that request to not found which is also handled by index.php